# Show that a path lies on a quadric surface

Tags: functions

We have the path of a particle determined as $\vec{x}(t)=(a\cos(t), b\sin(t), ct)$, $a, b, c > 0$, $t$ is time. If I want to show that the path lies on a quadric surface, do I have to derive a definite equation of the quadric surface? Or can I go about it implicitly?

I can show that the path is an oval: $(\frac{x}{a})^2 + (\frac{y}{b})^2 = 1$; and that $z=ct$, which implies that the particle "draws" a spiral oval as time goes.

I'm, however, wondering if we can show by an explicit formula that the oval spiral lies on an oval surface. My guess is no.

Comment: Aren't you done? You've just shown that all points on the curve lie on the oval cylinder surface defined by $(\frac{x}{a})^2 + (\frac{y}{b})^2 = 1$, which is a second-degree, irreducible equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parametrization is sufficient to say that you are extruding an ellipse and on that prism you are going up a helical a path. The surface is an elliptic cylinder as distinguished from the circular cylinder.

It need not lie on a quadric surfaces *alone*. A rigid helix can be drawn on an infinite set of blown in or blown out surfaces.

Mathematical formulation may be possible, but involved. I for one like to avoid math if a physical situation can be imagined.

If a wire-frame model of the helix is made and somehow made to enclose space,  dipped in a soap solution it spans a minimal surface. By putting in or taking our air into the inner space several surfaces of positive and negative Gauss curvature can be created as grooves or humps..

Unless a property of the surface is mentioned, a curve  cannot determine a surface on which it mounts.